# Dashboard Devmode w/o "Always on Top" Possible?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, dashboard

I am using (and loving) OS X's Dashboard in dev mode ('defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES') which lets you put the widgets on your desktop directly.

The only downside is the widgets are "always on top". So all windows end up going under the widgets instead of above. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

[Amnesty Widget Broswer](http://www.amnestywidgets.com/WidgetBrowser.html) (commercial product) claims, as one of its key features:

> Window level (desktop / standard / floating)

I haven't heard of any OS-ish way to turn off always-on-top.